# Unable to get any image to work as background image in CSS

Tags: html, css, background, local-files

I'm trying to add an image in my CSS file for a background from a local file. I've tried everything from ../img/img1.jpeg to just img1.jpeg, etc. I've even tried to add the website URL that the tutorial is using and it's still not working. This is what I'm working with so far.

Here is the CSS and HTML:

```css
  .intro {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("../img/Stone Wall Witch Hut Watermarked.jpeg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

```html
<secion class="intro">
  <nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#port">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#serv">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div ckass="inner">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Photography</h1>
      <p>my pictures</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

The URL I was using from the tutorial is:https://static.pexels.com/photos/248159/pexels-photo-248159.jpeg

The image I would like to use is in a Folder titled img. The parent folder is called Photography Starter Files. The img folder, HTML, and CSS are all in this. No matter what I put in the background, I cannot get anything to show up.

Comment: You have invalid HTML as there is a typo in `<secion class="intro">` (it's supposed to say `<section class="intro">`

Comment: Try to avoid white space and uppercase characters in your filenames. For example instead of Stone Wall Witch Hut Watermarked.jpeg, try using stone-wall-witch-hut-watermarked.jpg

Comment: As soon you as you fix the typo, it works for me

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by **blurfus** in the comments, you had an error in your HTML. The opening `<section>` tag was misspelled as `<secion>`. You also didn't have a closing `}` for the CSS in your snippet.

See the snippet below for a working version. You were very close! Note that I used the direct web link to your photo so it would work in the snippet.

```css
.intro {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/248159/pexels-photo-248159.jpeg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
    <nav>
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#port">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#serv">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div ckass="inner">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Photography</h1>
            <p>my pictures</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! To everyone who commented. I'm just dumb. Haha! My code does have the closing curly bracket in my CSS, I guess I missed it when I copied and pasted it. It's working now! Gotta work on proofreading, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can spot two errors that might be causing this.

1. the `.intro` tag in the `css` file is missing a closing curly brace
2. the `section` tag in the `html` file is spelled incorrectly

Otherwise it seems to be working fine. [Recreated your example](https://jsfiddle.net/the_high_ground_way/dgn038hz/1/)